# button selector binding issue on private / public closure

Tags: javascript, jquery, binding

I'm creating a set of JavaScript methods that will clone pre-existing HTML. Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="lib/pm-helpers.js"></script> -->
    <script src="lib/pm-ajax-inputs.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
    .hidden { display: none; }

</style>
<body>
    <script>
    jQuery( document ).ready( function() { 

        /*
        * Clone example 
        * the instance() method takes 3 parameters
        * @param: wrapper id or class
        * @param: clone group
        * @param: action button, image or link; something with a click event ability.
        */

        var instance = PM_CONTROLS.MODEL.PROPS.instance( '.first', '.control-group', '#clone' );
        instance.bind();

    } );
    </script>

    <ul class='first'>
        <li class='control-group'>
            <input type="text" name="discover[]"  value="" placeholder="info here" />
            <input type="button" id="bn-edit" class="green pm-edit" value="edit">
            <input type="button" id="bn-delete" class="blue pm-delete" value='delete'>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='second'>
        <li id='control-group2' class='controls '>
            <input type="text" name="discover[]"  value="" placeholder="info here" />
            <input type="button" id="bn-edit1" class="green pm-edit" value="farfenugal">
            <input type="button" id="bn-delete1" class="blue pm-delete" value='farfenay'>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="control-wrapper">
        <li class='controls'>
            <input type="text" name="discover[]"  value="" placeholder="control purpose here" />
            <input type="button" id="clone" class="green pm-add" value="add">
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="control-wrapper2">
        <li class='controls'>
            <input type="text" name="discover[]"  value="" placeholder="control purpose here" />
            <input type="button" id="clone1" class="green pm-add" value="add">
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Here is the JS:
        var PM_CONTROLS = PM_CONTROLS || {};

```
PM_CONTROLS.createNS = function ( namespace ) {

    var nsparts = namespace.split(".");

    var parent = PM_CONTROLS;

    // include or exclude the root namespace so we strip it if it's in the namespace
    if (nsparts[0] === "PM_CONTROLS") {

        nsparts = nsparts.slice(1);

    }

    // if required create a nested namespace by looping through the parts
    for (var i = 0; i < nsparts.length; i++) {

        var partname = nsparts[i];

        // check if the current parent already has the namespace declared
        // if it doesn't then create it
        if (typeof parent[ partname ] === "undefined") {

            parent[partname] = {};

        }

        // get a reference to the deepest element in the hierarchy
        parent = parent[ partname ];
    }

    // the parent is now constructed with empty namespaces and can be used.
    // we return the outermost namespace
    return parent;
};

PM_CONTROLS.createNS( 'PM_CONTROLS.MODEL.PROPS');

PM_CONTROLS.createNS( 'PM_CONTROLS.ACTIONS');

PM_CONTROLS.props = null;
PM_CONTROLS.i= 0;
PM_CONTROLS.MODEL.PROPS.instance = function ( wrapper_class_or_id, element_to_clone_id, clone_button_id  ) {


    var props = {
            wrapper : wrapper_class_or_id + PM_CONTROLS.i++
            , clone : element_to_clone_id + PM_CONTROLS.i
            , button : clone_button_id
    };

    var bind = function() {

        PM_CONTROLS.props = getProps();

        return new PM_CONTROLS.ACTIONS.bindAction();
    };

    var getProps = function() {
        return props;
    };

    return {

        bind : bind
        , getProps: getProps
    };
};


PM_CONTROLS.ACTIONS.clone = function() {

    var clone = $( PM_CONTROLS.props.clone ).clone();

    $( PM_CONTROLS.props.wrapper ).append( clone );

    clone.fadeIn('fast');



};

PM_CONTROLS.ACTIONS.bindAction = function () {


    $( PM_CONTROLS.props.button ).on( 'click', '', PM_CONTROLS.ACTIONS.clone() );
    //$( '#clone' ).click( PM_CONTROLS.ACTIONS.clone() );

};
```

So when running the HTML the ul with the class='control-group' is getting loaded into the PM_CONTROLS closures and properties.

Furthermore, the code steps through everything without any errors and the values that eventually get passed to the bindAction() method are correct ( I've hard-coded the selector for debugging purposes in the bindAction code ).

Can you explain why the HTML button with the id='#clone' is not binding a click event for the instance variable that is created?

Your help is appreciated on this one.

Regards,
Steve

Comment: Tssk, what's that empty parameter in `PM_CONROLS.ACTIONS.bindAction`? (hint: remove it). It's effecitvely saying: bind this function to element '*empty*' that is a child of `PM_CONTROLS.props.button`- Source: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Hey Tyblitz,changing to $( PM_CONTROLS.props.button ).on( 'click', PM_CONTROLS.ACTIONS.clone() ); does not do anything different. I had tried this and other variations before posting here. Also that 2nd parameter on the on( event, extra_data_passed_to_callback, callback function ) so really will it affect in the way you caution?

Comment: No, the second parameter specifies a child element of the `$()` element. It is often used  like so: `$(document).on('event', 'someButton', function);` because that sets the listener at document level (with event detection on the element). It also allows to bind to dynamically generated elements and reduce the amount of required listeners. Try removing the `()` from the function passed, I presume that's the problem, as you're in  effect executing the function and passing its return value to your event binding.

Comment: removing the (), causes the clone function not to be called when inpecting it in the debugger; whereas it does go through this function when clone() has the brackets.

Comment: Using the $(document).on('event', 'someButton', function); does bind the event correctly. Thank you!

Comment: Haha, I was still looking for other bugs, nice to know it works. Good luck

Comment: Yes thanks again. For those needing more clarity this line in the bindAction function is what works well: $(document).on('click', PM_CONTROLS.props.button, PM_CONTROLS.ACTIONS.clone);